# ¿Como mostrar un contador en una ventana y hacer que se cierre?

Tags: javascript

Buenas pues tengo este codigo en el que al darle a un boton se abre una ventana y aparece un contador que es un numero aleatorio entre 1 y 100, este cuenta hasta 0 y se cierra la ventana, pero no se muy bien que estoy haciendo mal ya que no me aparece nada en la ventana que abro.
Aqui dejo parte del codigo html porque decido abrirla dandodole a un boton y el javascript.

html:

```
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="Abrir" onclick="abrir()">
    
   
</body>
```

y javascript

```
var ventana;

function abrir() {
    ventana = window.open("", "new_window", "width=800,height=500,status=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no");
}

window.onload = contar;

function contar() {
    var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
    if (contartiempo == 0) {
        ventana.close();
    }

    ventana.document.write(" tu contador:<span id = contador></span>")//quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador

    
}
```

Comment: Intenta usar setInterval en vez del evento onload para llamar a la funcion `contar`. setInterval (function_,time): https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo optimizar este código?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/423003/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-optimizar-este-c%c3%b3digo)

Answer (score 1):

ya encontre la solucion a mi problema, aqui dejo el codigo para que vean que funciona, gracias a todos por los consejos.

```
window.onload = contar //para que cuando 
var contartiempo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

function contar() {
    if (ventana) {

        ventana.document.write(" <span id = contador></span>") //quiero que se muestre en la ventana abierta el contador
        ventana.document.getElementById('contador').innerHTML = contartiempo;
        if (contartiempo == 0) {
            ventana.close();
        } else {
            contartiempo -= 1;
            setTimeout("contar()", 1000);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Te apuesto a que este código no funciona, `setTimeout` no esta diseñado para llamar funciones con un string, debes hacer en su lugar: `setTimeout(contar,1000);` para pasarle la direccion de memoria de la funcion `contar` y así timeout pueda llamar a esa funcion, como lo enseño en este ejemplo: `try{
    setTimeout("hola()",1000,"Esto no se ejecutará");
}catch(e){ console.log("Error producido: "+e+"\nMensage: ");
    setTimeout(hola,1000,"Esto se ejecutará");
}
function hola(x){console.log("hola "+x);}`

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo así rápido, al hacer window.onload = contar deberías poner contar().

window.onload = contar()

Ya que este evento lo que hace es al cargar la pagina llama a la función que le pongas.

Comment: La funcion `contar` no retorna nada por lo que onload quedará en `NULL`, al hacer `contar();` llamas a la funcion contar aunqué la pagina no se haya cargado y asigna a `window.onload` un valor nulo porque la funcion `contar` no retorna nada, en cambio al hacer esto: `window.onload=contar;` le asigna al `onload` la direccion de memoria de la funcion `contar`, por lo que cuando el navegador llame a `onload` llamará realmente a la funcion `contar`.

Comment: puedes comprobarlo con esto: `function hola(){alert("Hola: )");}window.onload=hola();window.onload();` como notaras llamaremos a `hola` una ves y no dos veces, pero en cambio al hacer lo mismo pero de esta forma `hola;`: `function hola(){alert("Hola: )");}window.onload=hola;window.onload();` se llamará a la funcion hola dos veces, mostrando un saludo y un dibujo ANSI.

Comment: @DanielBriceño No veo que sea necesario retornar algo a `onload` dado que este es un evento. Por tanto, es correcto que se haga el llamado a la función cuando se produzca dicho evento.

Comment: @Alexis88 entonces porque harias esto: `window.onload=contar();` mejor as de una vez `contar();` pues estas haciendo lo mismo. Vamos a ver a otro evento... el `onclick`: imaginemos que tienes un boton con id `button`: `var button=document.getElementById("button");` ahora supongamos que quiero agregarle el onclick con la funcion `hola` anterior y de la forma que ustedes dicen: `hola();`: `button.onclick=hola();` veras que el navegador al entrar la pagina pues estas llamando de una vez a la funcion hola, pero ahora clicklea el boton.

Comment: @Alexis88 ... Sorpresa no pasa nada.:(), pero ahora vamos a hacerlo como yo dije: `hola;`: `button.onclick=hola;` guardemos la pagina ya modificada y recarguemos la pagina: Sorpresa al recargarla no sale ni una alerta, pero ahora preciona al boton y veras un buen saludo.:)

Comment: @Daniel Briceño Se hace esto `window.onload=contar();` con la finalidad de ejecutar la función al dispararse el evento `load`. Esto es de extrema ayuda si, por ejemplo, el código JS se encuentra en la cabecera del documento. Si esa función contempla elementos del DOM (que es lo más probable), y solo se colocara un `contar();`, ocurriría un error.

Comment: @DanielBriceño Con respecto al ejemplo del `onclick`, ocurre algo similar: se asocia la función al evento registrado en el elemento en cuestión, pero todo esto ocurriría una vez que la lectura del navegador haya alcanzado dicha línea de código. En este caso sería menos problemático que con el `onclick` porque, si se pretende ejecutar una función luego de haber cargado la página, necesariamente tiene que suceder al dispararse el evento `load`. De hecho, existe un evento llamado `readystatechange`, el cual ocurre cuando el atributo `readyState` de `document` ha cambiado.

Comment: @DanielBriceño Esos tres estados son:

- `loading`: Indica que el documento está cargando.

- `interactive`: Indica que ha cargado el DOM (que es lo que indica el evento `DOMContentLoaded`), mas no los elementos multimedia, hojas de estilo y código JS.

- `complete`: Indica la carga completa del documento y su contenido.

Esto le permite al desarrollador establecer la ejecución de distintos bloques de código según sea el estado. El caso de la publicación corresponde al estado `complete`, que es equivalente al evento `load`. Por ello la importancia de ejecutar la función asociada.

Comment: @DanielBriceño De cualquier forma, es preferible asociar los eventos y funciones que se ejecutan a los elementos del DOM con el método `addEventListener`.

Comment: `addEventListener` me salvado al usar canvas, pero no funciona al usar svg, creo que es mas porque es xml.